# external disc works bad on 1 of 3 usb port

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-3

I have a new pc with 3 usb ports (1 usb-2, and 2 usb-3).

My external disc works nicely on 2 usb ports.

But on one usb-3 ports, it's not working well.

The disk frequently stops (like every 5 minutes), and when it stops I have to wait 2-3 minutes for the disk to wake up.

Software ? Hardware ?

Comment: Do other devices on the same port also fail frequently?  And vice versa, does your external disk work on all other computers

Comment: Also, are you are it is not working on one of the USB3 ports? Asking since USB2 provides less power (max 500mW compared to max 900mW for USB3) and regular 2.5 inch drives seem to need about 650mWatt.

Comment: The hard disk works well on my other older computer, every usb ports. On my new computer, it's not working well on one of the two usb-3 ports.

Comment: This problem is not caused by software.

Comment: I had to delete my answer. The disk still becomes unrespondable after a while.  Really frustrating. Don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a call with HP support.
They made me upgrade the bios and reset windows.
Problem was still there.
So I'll send the pc to them and they'll change the usb part from the pc.
I'll see then if problem is solved.